# Adding int values in a string Android

Tags: android

[image]

I can't add up the int values in a string, I can not see why.

The string has been sent to a second activity by bundle and is displayed in a TextView now I need a Total of the value of the int String.

But Android always crashes, I have tried many different options but can not see why it does not work. A simple for loop should work: sum = sum + myArr[i].

Comment: Do not post your code as a image and post your logCat log of the crash.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple overloads for `setText()`. When you type in number the system is using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)), assuming the number is actually resource id. You should use `Integer.toString(sum)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this if it may help

```
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
        sum=sum+Integer.valueOf(myArr[i]);
    }
    Log.v("@@@WWe"," Sum :"+sum);
    textView3.setText(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this on `textView3.setText(" "+sum)` instead of `textView3.setText(sum)` this may solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

TextView expects String as a parameter.
You can achieve it by typecasting it to String or just by adding "" before or after your int (sum).

```
textView3.setText(sum+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Integer.valueOf(string)`, as it returns `Integer` objects. Instead use `Integer.parseInt(string)`, which returns a `int`. `valueOf()` wraps `parseInt()`.

Using either `valueOf()` or `parseInt()` you have to catch `NumberFormatException`. So try

```
int sum = 0;

try
{

    for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++)
    {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(myArr[i]);
    }

    textView3.setText(sum);
}
catch (NumberFormatException exception)
{
    // Handle exception.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`textView3.setText()`
the value cannot set int type.It should be String type.So try 
`texView3.setText(num+"")`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this to solve your problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      System.out.println(String.format("sum%s", String.valueOf(i)));
    }
```

It works well for me.
Good lucky